# How to factorize an operator?

Tags: c#, refactoring, operators

This may be very simple, but it's late in the night... I have two methods:

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetNotSticky()
{
   return Get().Where(p => p.Type != PostType.Sticky);
}
```

And the inverse

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetSticky()
{
   return Get().Where(p => p.Type == PostType.Sticky);
}
```

As you can see, the operator is the only difference. How to factorize this DRY violation into a nice common method? It feels simple, but right now the solution eludes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetWithSticky(bool isSticky)
{
   return Get().Where(p => (p.Type == PostType.Sticky) == isSticky);
}
```

Comment: Almost character for character, including parameter name, nice :-)

Comment: @yamen Except yours is broken.

Comment: @yamen awww, I thought it was funny; you didn't have to withdraw your answer.  Details, details.  :)  I should start another account called CaseSensitivityNazi. ;)